# Seek a react-plotly.js event handler example

Tags: reactjs, plotly.js

I use React & react-plotly.js component (https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js) to plot two charts.

Since these two charts share some of the legend name.(like before and after comparsion charts)

I would like them to response the same double click legend event (double click legend will show only that legend data on charts)

There is document in here: https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js/#event-handler-props

But is there any example for me to learn and get started?

Comment: I found this: https://codepen.io/mjhoffmann/pen/qVVEaZ